# Comparing elements one array with another of different lengths

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider an array1 of n no. of features

`array1=[feat1,feat2,...,featn]`

and array2 of m no. of linearRings

`array2=[ring1,ring2,...,ringm]`.

Now write a program in javascript such that every element of `array2` is compared with every element of `array1`.

PS: please suggest an approach apart from nested for loop.
The approach I tried:

```
features.map(feature => {
  linearRings.map(linearRing => {
    const singleFeature = getTurfFeature(feature);
    const pointOfLinearRing = point(
      transform(linearRing.getFirstCoordinate(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')
    );
    const checkForOverlap = booleanIntersects(pointOfLinearRing, singleFeature);
    checkForOverlap && feature.getGeometry().appendLinearRing(linearRing);
  });
});
```

Comment: you can use `Set`

Comment: Please show how you have tried to answer your homework

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @brk Could you please help me on how to solve t using "Set"

Comment: share your code and show what you tried

Comment: @brk edit your question and put the code there and properly format it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` & store the value of the first array here. Then you can check the result of `point` function and verify if it is present in set

```
const array1 = ['feat1', 'feat2', 'featn']
const set = new Set();
const array2 = ['ring1', 'ring2', 'ringm'];

array1.forEach(feature => {
  const singleFeature = getTurfFeature(feature);
  if (!set.has(singleFeature)) {
    set.add(singleFeature)
  }
})

array2.map(linearRing => {

  const pointOfLinearRing = point(
    transform(linearRing.getFirstCoordinate(), 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')
  );
  // do whatever you want to do here
  return set.has(pointOfLinearRing);
});
```